# selec2 search - Return no results found message if a specific criteria didnt match

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 4.0.3 for search drop down. As per my understanding its default functionality is not to match with the start of entries the drop down have. So I have implemented the below given code

```
function matchStart(params, data) {
    params.term = params.term || '';
    if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
        return data;
    }
    return false;
}

$("select").select2({
    placeholder : "Input country name or select region",
    matcher : function (params, data) {
        return matchStart(params, data);
    },
});
```

My problem is, the dropdown is not showing "No results found" message even if there is no matching results found. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return value of `matchStart` from `false` to `null`.

Also you can remove the extra function around the `matcher` argument. The result:

```
function matchStart(params, data) {
    params.term = params.term || '';
    if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
        return data;
    }
    return null;
}

$("select").select2({
    placeholder: "Input country name or select region",
    matcher: matchStart
});
```